# Does the leveldb that uses hyperledger fabric compress the data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, leveldb

We know that leveldb compresses by default on snappy, but, when I get to the folder of production data, ledgers data I see the following folders:

- bookkeeper
- chains
- configHistory
- historyLeveldb
- ledgerProvider
- pvtdataStore

On chains I can see the channel created, and there is a block with all the data uncompressed, I can see everything clearly. The file is 33MB and I can see that there are all the operations that have been done for the channel, configurations, upgrades..

On the historyLeveldb I can see another file much smaller, with .ldb extension and what appears to be compressed.

When does leveldb compress a file? What are the roles of those 2 folders and files? When querying the ledger, what file does it query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual ledger (aka "blockchain") is file-based.  These files are not compressed.

The state database (which stores the latest values for all keys) uses LevelDB (or CouchDB).

When performing operations such as "GetState", the state database is queried.  When calling APIs to access blocks and transactions, there is an database which maintains indexes/pointers to the file ledger and the actual data is returned from the ledger files.